# Cancel goroutine on new function call

Tags: go, concurrency

I need to cancel any previous `goroutine` on every function call.  How would that be handled in Go?  I've seen channels used but I can't quite wrap my head around the examples and whether a select statement is necessary.

The desired result would be that only the last request subtasks are ran.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        go handleRequest(i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // Time between requests
    }
}

func handleRequest(incr int) {
    fmt.Println("New request registered: ", incr + 1)
    for i := 0; i <= 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Request: ", incr + 1, " | Sub-task: ", i + 1)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // Time processing
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goroutine cancellation can be done using a context. If you need to cancel a previous goroutine, start it with a context and cancel it when a new one starts. You have to write the goroutine to periodically check for the context:

```
   var ctx context.Context
   var cancel context.CancelFunc
   for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
        if cancel!=nil {
             // cancel previous goroutine
             cancel()
        }
        ctx,cancel=context.WithCancel(context.Background())
        // start goroutine with a new context
        go handleRequest(ctx,i)
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second) // Time between requests
    }  
    if cancel!=nil {
       cancel() 
    }
```

In your goroutine, you have to check for cancellation:

```
func handleRequest(ctx context.Context,incr int) {
    fmt.Println("New request registered: ", incr + 1)
    for i := 0; i <= 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Request: ", incr + 1, " | Sub-task: ", i + 1)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second) // Time processing
        select {
           case <-ctx.Done():
             // canceled
             return
           default:
             // not canceled
        }
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: What kind of an `if`? `select` with default is how you do nonblocking read.

Comment: Is there a way handle the cancellation at a higher level and more immediately?  After looking at it, it seems there could be a race condition where in `handleRequest` if a long process occurs before the select statement. Say a new request hits in `main` immediately after the `select` is hit in `handleRequest` goroutine.  The subtask in the previous `handleRequest` would still process before hitting the select statement again to register the context is done.

Comment: No. If you're worried about other goroutines doing things that may affect the canceled goroutine, then check cancelation multiple times, and every time before you do something that can be affected. There is no other way to cancel a goroutine.

Comment: Nice & easy, thanks. But it should be `go handleRequest(ctx,i)` in line 10 (context first), or the code will not compile.